# Sanitize a grabbed attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, exploit

I grab a href value like this:

```
var $url = jQuery('body').find('.download a').attr('href');
```

How to I sanitize this value? I tried adding `.text()` but didn't work.

Comment: "Sanitize"?  How do you mean?

Comment: What do you mean by 'sanitize' it? How you do that would depend on where you want to use it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan With sanitize, I mean, how do I escape it? I will use this value in a variety of way so want to stop the user from adjusting this value in an attempt to exploit the site.

Comment: use  sanitize-html.js for this...use this you can achieve this... for more info https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html

Comment: @Darshak Is there no way to do this without using a third-party code?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson `I will use this value in a variety of way so want to stop the user from adjusting this value in an attempt to exploit the site.` How will you do that?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson You could do it without 3rd party code, but you would just be reinventing the wheel. Often it is better to use a 3rd party library, especially for stuff like this. An open-source library has likely already been tested over a wide range of situations and may account for stuff you don't think of, thus likely being more secure than a do-it-yourself solution. Don't fall victim to the "not invented here syndrome", it will more often hurt you than help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of things you need consider depending on where you need to use `$url`.

[This link is very useful, apply principals as you read](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

I'm sure the above link provides either a fundamental knowledge or checklist for every JS engineer trying to create secure software.